# Slack on MacOS: Keeping Sidebar open

Tags: mac, slack

Slack rolled out a new UX change recently that auto-hides the sidebar (at least on MacOS). Is there any way I can keep it open? I found this in preferences under "sidebar" but it is what to show in the sidebar. What I want is a preference for "always show sidebar."

[image: Sidebar prefs]

Am I missing something? (I am aware of the Cmd-Shft-D shortcut to expand... just don't want to have to do that all the time)

Answer (score 10):

I pinged Slack support and they got back to me 45m later. This basically solved this for me. I highlighted the parts that were critical for me. It has to do with the ratio of widths.

> Fazil here from Slack Support. (...)
>
> When it comes to the sidebar automatically disappearing, this would
> only happen **if your Slack window is too narrow** and I wonder if this
> might be what's happening in your case as well. **You could try
> expanding the width threshold by resizing your sidebar to be smaller**.
>
> (...)

Note that it also might be **the width of the thread/profile/etc. panel on the right that is causing the issue - if it's too wide, then the sidebar also starts to autohide**.

Amazing support. Thanks Slack!

Answer (score 1):

Make the font size smaller smaller (on a Mac) with Command - (minus sign) and then the menu will remain visible. If you use Command + it'll make the font bigger and at some point the sidebar will collapse. This works without having to resize your Slack window.

Answer (score 0):

A subtle cause can be undocking your laptop. You may have the right panel (e.g. for threads) set to a size that makes sense on a large external monitor. When you undock and your window resizes to fit your laptop display, the right panel's width may now be large enough to force the left sidebar to collapse.

In general, if the left sidebar is visible, resizing the Slack window should automatically resize right panel to keep the left sidebar visible. I provided this to Slack as a feature suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I had to close the current opened Thread panel and then make the Sidebar smaller. Then I was able to open one thread again and the Sidebar did not disappear anymore.